# Adding letters, spaces, and removing parts of attribute string in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression, string, text

I have an attribute of the form:

```
12-06-065-03 W4M
```

and would like it in the following form:

```
LSD-12 SEC-06 TWP-065 RGE-03 MER-4
```

Comment: Most of this is straightforward, but how does `W4M` get handled?  Does the 4 get extracted and the W and M dropped, or does the W or M possibly impact what happens to the 4?

Comment: If the OP never returns, these seem to be Canadian "legal land descriptions": https://www.alberta.ca/alberta-township-survey-system.aspx  - Quarter (LSD), Township, Range, Meridian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QGIS has a bunch of string processing functions in its expression engine. You can use these to extract bits of strings, do replacements, split on characters etc etc.

For example this expression extracts parts of your input string (in column `x2`) and re-formats it with the labels you seem to want to add. This only works if your inputs have the same letters in the same positions every time:

```
format('LSD-%1 SEC-%2 TWP-%3 RGE-%4 MER-%5',
 substr(x2, 1,2),
 substr(x2,4,2),
 substr(x2,7,3),
 substr(x2,11,3),
 substr(x2,15,1)
 )
```

You can use expressions in lots of places in QGIS, such as the labelling dialog, or in the attribute editor you can create a new column based on an expression. Here's the results of applying that expression on some values like your example:

[image]

Note that if the format varies you may need a different approach. If your values might look like "912-06-1065-03 W99M" (ie variable number of digits in any field) then `substr` won't work and you'll need to look at a split or regexp approach.

Answer (score 7):

Convert the input string to an array with [`string_to_array()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#string-to-array), then you can access each element separately by it's index (`[0]` for the first) and concatenate it with the additional strings you want to add. This has the advantage that it works even if the textual/numerical elements in the input string have varying lengths. Use this expression:

```
with_variable(
    'array',
    string_to_array (replace ("your_input_field",' ','-'),'-'),
    'LSD-'  || @array[0] || 
    ' SEC-' || @array[1] || 
    ' TWP-' || @array[2] || 
    ' REG-' || @array[3] || 
    ' MER-' || regexp_matches (@array[4], '(\\d+)')[0]
)
```

[image]

---

You did not mention how to treat the last element, what rule applies to convert `W4M` -> `MER-4`. I added a regular expression function [`regexp_matches()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#regexp-matches) to extract the digit(s) from the input and add it after the string `'MER-'`.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions with the function [`regexp_replace()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/de/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#regexp-replace). Use [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to capture those elements from the string you want to keep and call them using [backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) (like `\\1` to call the first capturing group) and add the additional elements you need. To do so, use this expression:

```
regexp_replace(
    "input_string",
    '(\\d*)-(\\d*)-(\\d*)-(\\d*)\\s\\D*(\\d*).*',
    'LSD-\\1 SEC-\\2 TWP-\\3 RGE-\\4 MER-\\5'
)
```

[image]